# Can I use a custom module resolution function (like "proxyquire") in place of require() with TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, proxyquire

I have a TypeScript file `config.ts` that will be run with node:

```
import myDependency = require('my-dependency');    

export = {
    doSomething = () => {
        ...
    }
}
```

In other TypeScript file, I can `import` this file with full type safety:

```
import config = require('./config');
config.doSomething();
config.doSomethingElse(); // compiler error, this method doesn't exist
```

Now I want to unit test this script. In order to mock out the dependencies that this script `require()`s I'm using [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire), which lets me provide the values that my script will get when it makes calls to `require()`.  Here's what my test might look like:

```
import proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const config = proxyquire('./config', {
    'my-dependency': {} // this mocked object will be provided when config.ts asks for `my-dependency`
});

expect(config.doSomething()).to.do.something();
```

This works fine, except that my `config` variable is of type `any` because I'm using `proxyquire()` in place of `require()`.  TypeScript must give the `require()` function special treatment to allow it to perform module resolution.  Is there a way to tell the TypeScript compiler that `proxyquire()` should also do module resolution, similar to `require()`?

I could rewrite `config.ts` as a class or make it use an interface. Then I would be able to explicitly type the variables in my tests by importing the class/interface definition.  But allowing `proxyquire()` to implicitly type things for me would be far be the easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround - you can get the type of `config.ts` module by importing actual module and using `typeof` in a type cast:

```
import proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

import configType = require('./config');

const config = <typeof configType> proxyquire('./config', {
    'my-dependency': {} // this mocked object will be provided when config.ts asks for `my-dependency`
});

config.doSomething();

// config.noSuchMethod(); // does not compile
```

This is not ideal because you have to import the same module in your test twice - the real one just to get at the type of it and "proxiquired" one to actually use in your tests, and you have to be careful not to mix up the two. But it's pretty simple compared to the task of implementing another variant of module resolution for typescript. Also, when configType is used in this way - for typing only - its import will not even appear in generated javacsript code.